# previous Eclipse Neon installation does't start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, eclipse

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and, after the upgrade, my previous Eclipse Neon installation doesn't work anymore. If I launch it I see the splash screen, it disappears and then nothing else. On console and in log I don't receive any errors.

I tried adding `SWT_GTK3=0` or `SWT_GTK3=1` in the environments, removing `-Dorg.eclipse.core.net.enableGnome` option I had in command line, using default VM (I was using JDK 1.8.0) and in eclipse.ini the settings:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

but nothing works. I'm bound to this Eclipse version because it's the one adopted in my company. Any suggestion?

EDIT

Cleaning workspace as stated in the comment is a temporary solution. It's necessary to specify `SWT_GTK3=0` to avoid workspace corruption in subsequent run.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and I don't receive any errors, so they doesn't seems related.

Comment: I'm bond to Eclipse Neon because it's the version adopted in my company

Comment: I was able to open Eclipse again simply adding "-clean -clearPersistedState" options.